# Move one stud fron interior load bearing wall

Tags: walls

Studs are 16" center in an interior load bearing wall,one story house,  I need an additional 5". Can I replace the stud at 21" without a header.

Comment: Do you mean move a stud at 16" to 21"?

Comment: Why do you need 5 extra inches?  Can always add an extra stud at the 5 inch mark if needed to hang/mount something.  Makes life easier if don't need to fool around with load bearing.  Most codes(building) list minimums needed, extras are good.

Comment: Need to remove pre-existing stud . I need the additional 5 ". Creating a niche for refrigerator door to open into.

Comment: Pictures are going to help a lot.  Fridges are usually not placed inside walls and 21 inches is a tiny fridge.  Unless an old 40s fridge most fridge doors are only about an inch thick.  Basically I am lost on what you want.

Comment: To remove old and place new stud 5 inches away would require opening up enough wall where adding a header wouldn’t be that much extra work. That said, I don’t think it’s necessary depending on how long that wall is. If it only had two or three stud bays to begin with, it may be prudent to add a header. If it’s a long wall, one stud moved 5 inches wouldn’t make much of a difference.

Comment: Are you trying to recess the refrigerator into the wall cavity?

Comment: move the refrigerator hinges to the other side. (you will need a screwdriver, and possibly a wrench)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Wall is 16 ft long, trying to create a niche in the wall for the french door of refrigerator to recess into. The current wall is restricting the door from totaling opening.  The specs on frig did not include the door swinging open , i had 2" clearance,  obviously not enough.

Comment: Perhaps a drawing of what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful. I'm trying to envision how/why you'd need to recess the open door of the fridge into the wall and can't, for the life of me, imagine why you'd need that extra clearance when the door's open. After all, most people don't have the door open for longer than the 2-3 minutes it takes to stare in there when rummaging for a midnight snack. TBH, this is sounding like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I can't figure out how to post pic. Door won't open enough to remove crisper for cleaning. Would have to pull refrigerator out